# rails 4.2.6 digest fingerprint is 32-character in application.html.erb but 64-character on file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, assets, fingerprint

Rails 4.2.6, running on unicorn, AWS server, I'm running into a problem where in development, in application.html.erb, this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

renders as:

```
/assets/application-74379e2c156a9bc2dcabee034283e935ad917ff7fc300f7995f67bf5833c26cf.js
```

(64 character fingerprint)

and in my production-like demo environment this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

renders as:

```
/assets/application-c200f4e6eb576ae5f2edb02fd5772e73.js
```

(32 character fingerprint)

Which the server can't find the file because it's not the correct fingerprint as the file has the 64 character fingerprint.

I can't find where to change the settings that it renders the correct 64 character fingerprint.

I've been searching through rails guides and google, of course, stackoverflow, much of which is for earlier versions of rails or heroku, but nothing seems to point to this specific problem.

Here's my configuration file:

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
config.serve_static_assets = false #(tried setting this to true with same result)

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
config.assets.version = '1.1'

# Code is not reloaded between requests.
config.cache_classes = true

# config.assets.compress = true

config.assets.compile = false

config.assets.digest = true

#config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
#config.assets.precompile += %w( '.woff', '.eot', '.svg', '.ttf' )

# Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
# your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
# and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
# Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
config.eager_load = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Comment: [asset not precompilling properly](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/07/20/ruby-on-rails-production-staging-when-asset-path-is-outdated/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, although for me assets:clean didn't exist, but assets:clobber did, I'm left in the same spot, the files are regenerated with 64 character fingerprint, and application.html.erb points to one that is 32-character. What tells applciation.html.erb what the fingerprint is?

Comment: As an update, I've deleted all release folders and redeployed and my log file shows that templates can't be found and it's looking in a release folder that doesn't exist anymore. Definitely a part of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking to solve this problem, cap was deploying using a different ruby than my environment. Stemmed from an mixed setup using both RVM and rbenv. I only saw this problem because of brute forcing minute changes and seeing what spilled in the logs. #diggingholes